# Is the Add New User Model Extension compatible with Web 8?

Tags: web8, user-management

I have been spinning up new Web 8 instances very much lately; either upgrade or clean install and I just now went back to look at a few and noticed that the `CreateUnlisted` button doesn't exist anymore.

It was issued for 2011 and was definitely compatible with 2013.

Anyone else look into this?

If it were there, it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Yea, Web8 architecture changed significantly and this is not compatible anymore (without tweaking of course)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've actually never heard of that extension (and Google didn't reveal anything), so you'd have to check with whoever wrote it. It might take some effort for them to update it. If it's open source, you could look into contributing a solution yourself.

That said, allow me to plug two solutions of my own, as alternatives to the  user creation wizard:

1. The [Add User by Name](http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Add-User-By-Name) Alchemy plugin.
2. The New-TridionUser cmdlet which is part of the [Tridion PowerShell Modules](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules).

Both of them are [open source](https://github.com/pkjaer/) and available to everyone for free.

Comment: It's issued by SDL and essentially it's for large companies when you configure Tridion/Web8 to use active directory. For example, 25k or 100k+ AD size, will take a very long time to find a user using only the 'search' if it even returns any result.

Comment: In that case, check out the alternatives I listed. They both solve the issue.

Comment: The performance issue can also be tackled by configuring you AD as a Directory Service and then specifying "Directory Service" instead of "Domain" for Directory Type;  LDAP lookups are much faster in general and if you also specify part of the user name in "Search for User(s)", it will be very fast.